# Trying to reuse Spring JdbcTemplate connection for Postgres JDBC copyIn - getting 'relation does not exist'

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-jdbc

I've hit a brick wall in a Spring/Kotlin/JDBC/Postgres project and am hoping the community can help.

**What I'm Trying To Do**

- Use Spring JDBC API (`JdbcTemplate`) to create a temporary table (`temporary_pokemon`) in a Postgres database.
- Unwrap the JDBC connection from the `JdbcTemplate` so I can use the same connection to load a CSV into the database using the Postgres JDBC driver's `copyIn` method (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyIn.html)

**What Is Going Wrong**

The `copyIn` method errors with the message `relation "temporary_pokemon" does not exist`, and my assumption here is that the unwrapped connection is somehow separate/different to the `db.execute` command which creates the table.

Ideally there's a way to re-use the same connection while still being able to rely largely on Spring Boot's autoconfiguration and things like automatic connection pooling, etc.

**What I've Tried So Far**

- Adding the `@Transactional` annotation
- Creating a `DataSource` manually using Spring Boot's `DataSourceBuilder` (this seems to work, I am assuming that it only creates a single connection which gets reused)

**The error message**

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "temporary_pokemon" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1212) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.startCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:894) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager.copyIn(CopyManager.java:45) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager.copyIn(CopyManager.java:177) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager.copyIn(CopyManager.java:160) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at com.example.demo.IngestPostgres.ingest(IngestPostgres.kt:32) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.demo.IngestPostgres$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f1321c17.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

**Code Snippets**

My `@Component` for the `CommandLineRunner`:

```
@Component
class Seed : CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var ingester : IngestPostgres

    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        val buffer = BufferedReader(FileReader(File("src/main/resources/ingest.csv")))
        ingester.ingest(buffer)
    }
}
```

The `IngestPostgres` `@Component`:

```
@Component
class IngestPostgres {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var db: JdbcTemplate

    @Transactional
    fun ingest(bufferedReader: BufferedReader) {
       db.execute("""
           DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temporary_pokemon;
           CREATE TABLE temporary_pokemon (
             pokemon_id INT,
             pokemon_name VARCHAR,
             pokemon_type VARCHAR
           );
       """.trimIndent())

        val pgConnection = db.dataSource?.connection?.unwrap(PgConnection::class.java)!!

        CopyManager(pgConnection).copyIn(
            "COPY temporary_pokemon FROM stdin DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER",
            bufferedReader
        )

        // snipped - later code INSERTS contents of temporary_pokemon into main pokemon table
    }
}
```

My dependencies in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Thanks for any help. I'm not an expert at Spring/JDBC by any means, so apologies in advance if I've missed something that's common knowledge. I've tried searching on SO and Google but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your queries use different connections. So results of first query are not committed when the second query starts. You can get a single connection and use it for execution of both queries or use JdbcTemplate api for importing csv data to your table